# Access one usecase into another usecase

Tags: python, clean-architecture

I am working on machine learning project. I use `jupyter` for quick prototying. Now I am trying to convert it into concrete python project using clean architecture.

- **entities/**

```
    - problem.py   # contain type_name can be regression or classification
      
      class Problem:
        type_name: str
```

- **usecases/**

  - **problem_usecase.py**   # get_type() and set_type(name: str)

```
      class ProblemUsecase:
         
         def __init__(self, repo: ProblemRepositoryInterface):
            self._repo = repo
            
         def get_type():
           type_name = self._repo.get_type() 
           retutn type_name
           
         def set_type(name: str):
           status = self._repo.set_type(name) 
           retutn status
```

- **acquire_usecase.py**  # use to split given dataset into train, test, val

```
    from adapters.problem_repository import ProblemRepository  # Is this breaking rule
    class AcquireUsecase:
    
      def __init__(self, repo: AcquireRepositoryInterface):
            self._repo = repo
            
            
          def create_datasets():
          
             problem_type = ProblemUsecase(repo=ProblemRepository()).get_type()    # I need to access problem type name
             
             if problem_type == "classification":
                do some job
             elif problem_type == "regression":
                do some job
```

- **interfaces/**

```
         - problem_repository_interface.py
         - acquire_repository_interface.py
```

- **adapters/**   # actual implementation

  - **problem_repository.py**
    ```
    class ProblemRepository:

    ````
              def __init__():
                 self._repo = Redis or Postgres Instance


              def get_type():
                return self._repo.hget(key)  # say using redis
     ```
    ````
  - **acquire_repository.py**

As `AcquireUsecase` needs the `problem type name` from `ProblemUsecase`, I read components within the same circle and below its layer have access.

1. Is the way I have access above 2 usecases ok ?
2. If yes, then passing the `ProblemRepository()` as argument `repo` to `ProblemUsecase()` I need to import it from `adapter layer`(problem_repository.py) into `usecase layer`(acquire_usecase.py) which I guess breaking the clean architecture rule.

Can someone suggests how one usecase can be used in another usecase?

Comment: `ProblemUsecase` doesn't really seem to do anything - is it *really* a use case? If not, delete it, then in `AcquireUsecase`, do: `__init__(self, acquireRepo: AcquireRepositoryInterface, problemRepo: ProblemRepositoryInterface)`. Or even move the "get/set problem type" methods to the `AcquireRepositoryInterface` to make a repository that's oriented towards the needs of the use case (a design more in line with CA), rather than have a number of repos based around how you structured the underlying data model.

Comment: Hi  Filip, Thanks. I am saving the `problem` entity in `postgres` database. For sample code, I have listed few attributes. Just like `ProblemUsecase`, I have entity as `dataset` that contains dataset info. For eg target(can be name of column or index number) and this handle by `DatasetUsecase` which I am storing in `postgres` database.

Comment: For the above mentioned `AcquireUsecase` as it need `problem type name` from `ProblemUsecase`, It also need `target column` from `DatasetUsecase`. I am thinking to create a `service` for each usecase and in that I can pass the actual `repo` [can be redis or postgres] and accessing these `api services` within the different usecases and also using the same `service api` in the infrastructure inside `web app`. Does this approach make sense?